# AngularJS >=1.3: ng-if with one time binding that is removed when expression evaluates to true

Tags: angularjs

I make heavy use of this trick

```
ng-if="::vm.isLoaded || undefined"
```

In this case, if `vm.isLoaded` is anything falsey the watch will continue to operate because `undefined` is always returned in that case, and the "one time binding" continues to watch until the expression evaluates to something other than `undefined`.

Is there any way to achieve the reverse?  Ie keep watching truthy values until the expression evaluates to `undefined`, or some other "magic" value.

A real use case is a Loading... gif, which once the content is loaded, needs to disappear.

```
ng-if="!vm.isLoaded"
```

works fine (shows the loading gif while loading, and hides it once loaded), but once the stuff is loaded, I want the watch to be removed (the stuff will never become "unloaded" again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying over from [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15372):

Negative `ngIf` with one-time binding is indeed not possible currently and is a usecase (the only one afaik) that makes `ngUnless` (the opposite of `ngIf`) enable something that is not already possible.

A more verbose work-around for achieving what you want is to use `ngSwitch` (although this adds an extra DOM element - which you can hide of course).

```
<div ng-switch="::(foo || undefined)">
  <div ng-switch-when="undefined">
    This text will be removed for ever,
    once `foo` evaluates to something truthy
  </div>
</div>
```

---

That said, `ngIf` is just a plain old directive (and not a complex one for that matter), so it is not difficult to copy and modify its source code and include it in your app.

Here is an ["ngUnless"-like demo](https://codepen.io/ExpertSystem/pen/zoxXeG?editors=1011).

Answer (score 0):

**`$watch returns a deregistration function.`**

You can `unregister` a `$watch` with the function returned by the `$watch` call:

```
var unwatch = $scope.$watch('isLoaded', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if(newValue == false || newValue == undefined)
    {
        unwatch();
    }
});
```

So, once your `isLoaded` becomes `false` or `undefined`, the `watch` on it is removed.

Comment: Well, OK, but your watch is created (and destroyed) in code. I still need to have an expression for the `ng-if` in the template to watch.  And that's the watch I'm trying to have destroyed.

Comment: you might have an expression in `ng-if`, it is not watched any more, once it gets destroyed

Comment: let me post you an example

Comment: checked that link?

Comment: In that example, your `$watch("count", ...` is indeed destroyed, but the `ng-show` will continue to watch `after_unwatch` forever. If you put `::ng-show...` _that_ watch will be destroyed when it evaluates to `true` because of Angular bind-once. But that's not my use case.  I want `ng-if` to _remove_ something from the DOM and stop watching once `isLoaded` becomes truthy.

Comment: once your `is_loaded` becomes true, it will not be watched again

Comment: I changed my ans pls check, I understood you need the opposite thing

Comment: I read your updated answer.  My original comment still applies. "...your watch is created (and destroyed) in code. I still need to have an expression for the `ng-if` in the template to watch. And that's the watch I'm trying to have destroyed."

Comment: dont you want `ng-if="!vm.isLoaded"` this to be destroyed?

Comment: Sravan, I don't think we're getting any closer.  Let's start with some basic Angular theory...  When you put `ng-if="blah"` the `blah` is watched automatically by Angular, because otherwise it won't respond when `blah` changes.  I'm trying to remove the watch that Angular adds to an `ng-if` using something like "bind-once", but in my case, remove it after it evaluates to falsey (or some special value if necessary) from a previously truthy value. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-hide="::vm.isLoaded || undefined"
```

This doesn't directly answer the question, because I really wanted to use `ng-if` to remove the loading gif from the DOM altogether.

But hiding it and removing the watch is the next best thing.  I'm not sure of the relative performance issue of accumulating dead hidden DOM elements vs accumulating dead watches.

What I really need is a negative version of `ng-if`.  Like `ng-notif`. :P